# Get the content inside shortcode and apply external function to it?

Tags: content, shortcode

```
function t_shortcode($atts, $content = null){
$lang = strtolower($atts['lang']);

$content = "<div id='translator' class='translate_".$lang."'>".$content."</div>";
if($lang == $_SESSION['language']):

    return $content;
endif;

}
```

I'm trying to get the content between the shortcodes, apply a function to it in index.php and the return back the $content of the shortcode with the divs included.

the second function that i'd like to apply to the shorcode function is:

```
function display($shortcodecontent, $noofchars){
$content2 = mb_substr($shortcodecontent,0,$noofchars);
return $content2;
}
```

so that I can use:
     // 13 is the number of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following adds the shortcode `[my_t_shortcode]`, which accepts an attribute 'lang', and applys the above mentioned function to the content.

```
//Add shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'my_t_shortcode', 'wpse41477_shortcode_handler' );

//It's good practise to make sure your functions are prefixed by something unique
function wpse41477_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content = null ) {
       //This will extract 'lang' attribute as $lang. You can supply default values too.
       extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'lang' => 'default_lang',
          ), $atts ) );
    //The above lowercases all values.

    /* Apply external function. 'display' is too generic, 
     * give it a unique prefix to prevent a clash with another plugin/theme/WordPress 
     */
    $content = wpse41477_display($content,13);
    //why not do $content = mb_substr($content,0,13); instead?

    //Apply divs
    $content = "<div id='translator' class='translate_".$lang."'>".$content."</div>";

    //Not sure what the following is for, but I've left it in.
    if($lang == $_SESSION['language']):
        return $content;
    endif;
    }
```

And the custom function:

```
function wpse41477_display($shortcodecontent, $noofchars){
     $content2 = mb_substr($shortcodecontent,0,$noofchars);
return $content2;
}
```

If that all `wpse41477_display` does, I would strongly recommend that you include it directly in the shortcode handler (see the comments).

*The above code is not tested.*

Comment: The thing is that I need to use a code like that in the index.php <? php wpse41477_display(13) ?> so it would display 13 characters of the content and apply the div on it from the first function

Comment: @MohamedSaid - do you mean to say you want to apply this shortcode only on index.php? Is there a reason why you want to use `mb_substr` rather than the  [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) with the length set to 13? (See link, section Control Excerpt Length using Filters).